# Sending source data that fails to get a row from Lookup T/F

Tags: informatica

I have look up T/F in the mapping. If the look up t/f fails to return a row based on the look up condition, i need to send the source record to Bad file. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add an Update Transformation with a condition like:

```
IIF(ISNULL(lkp_Id), DD_REJECT, DD_INSERT)
```

Where lkp_Id is a name of port fetched by lookup transformation.